# shapes (3,1) and (3,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Here is defined function and as result it has to be an scalar but when the function is called I get this error: shapes (3,1) and (3,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

```
def Angle_sun(panel):
  print(panel)
  sun = np.array([[0], [-1368], [0]])
  dott = np.dot(panel, sun)
  return math.acos(dott/(np.linalg.norm(panel)) * np.linalg.norm(sun))
```

where panel = [[0.  ],[0.92], [0.39]]

panel is a (3,1)

Comment: Please take a look at [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are expected to add code and data as text, since we can not copy the contents from image.

Comment: Did you reread the `np.dot` docs?  Understand how it handles dimensions, including the case where one array is 1d?  Do you understand the shape of the arguments to the `dot`?

Comment: What should `dott` be?  (3,3) or scalar?  The matrix product of a (3,1) with (1,3) or, vector dot of a (3,) with (3,)?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [matrix dot product (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) , for `a.b` the required matrices should have size of `NxM` and `MxN` respectively. If you look at the [`numpy.dot documentation`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), you'll know what output is generated for different shapes of the matrices passed to it.

> numpy.dot(a, b, out=None)
> Dot product of two arrays. Specifically,
> If both a and b are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors
> (without complex conjugation).
>
> If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using
> matmul or a @ b is preferred.
>
> If either a or b is 0-D (scalar), it is equivalent to multiply and
> using numpy.multiply(a, b) or a * b is preferred.
>
> If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over
> the last axis of a and b.
>
> If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum
> product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b

Since `sun` matrix above has the dimension of `3x1`, and you are performing `panel.sun`, the `panel` matrix should have the dimension of `1x3`, then dot product of two matrices with shapes `1x3`, and `3x1` will be `1x1`.

So, the panel list you have should be 1D list i.e. `[0.0, 0.92, 0.39]`, instead of `[[0.0], [0.92], [0.39]]` which is a 2D list of course.